# matlab svds() returns empty matrix []

Tags: matlab

Under what circumstances will `Matlab` function `svds()` returns `[]`?

I not sure whether there are something wrong with my input data?

What kinds of input will lead to such problem in `svds()`?

The link of the data Kn:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/foco36llty8ul29/Kn.mat?dl=0

Load it then run:

```
Kn=(Kn+Kn')/2;
D=1./sqrt(sum(Kn,2));
D=sparse(diag(D));
LAP=D*sparse(Kn)*D;
[~, S, V] = svds(LAP,51);
```

My `S`,`V` is `[]`.

Comment: P.S.  my command is like, [~,s,v] = svds(A) and s,v is empty matrix []

Comment: Uhm... what does your matrix `A` look like?  Do you think perhaps your input is....empty?  What does `numel(A)` give you?  0?

Comment: A is not empty but quite large(thousands x thousands) and sparse. What's more, I use sparse(A) to save memory

Comment: What is the rank of your matrix?  Type in `rank(A)` and tell me what you get.  `svds` by default returns the 6 largest singular values and the corresponding singular vectors.  Should you provide a matrix whose rank is less than 6, that could explain why you're getting nothing.

Comment: when I run rank(A), something goes wrong, It said "Error using svd" "Use svds for sparse singular values and vectors"

Comment: Maybe if you post more of your code someone will be able to help. Matlab's error message are *very useful*! Read them fully and think about what they are saying.

Comment: The dropbox link doesn't seem to work. Can you make a very small `Kn` matrix that still exhibits the problem?